# I'm executing the script for 1 hr but it is running for 10 min

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I'm executing the script for 1 hour but it is running for 10 minutes , i also check loop forever, test data is also proper, all the script is running properly without any error , I run the script thrice validate all the things but im not getting why it is happening

How to overwrite the issues and how to run a the script for 1 hour

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can find the reason for termination of a thread or test in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging). If it is not there or it's vague - you can [increase JMeter logging level](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) to something [more verbose](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_levels.htm)

The most common reasons for premature end of the test are:

1. Not enough loops to cover the anticipated duration of the test in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
2. Not enough test data if [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) is configured to stop thread on EOF
3. Thread group is configured to stop the thread/test on a sampler error
4. There is [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler somewhere configured to stop thread/test
5. There is a runtime error like [OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html) or [StackOverFlowError](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stack-overflow-error)